# ListBox Row Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, listboxitem, listboxitems, listbox-control

i want to ask something about ListBox in Windows Phone

how to split 1 row listbox into 2 column?

i want to show item like this image:

[image: example design]

the list is contain news from RSS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WrapPanel](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=176) from the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) to accomplish that kind of layout.

Comment: thanks Garrett, i will try it.. im beginner with windows phone dev